# c# with SOAP - problem with utf-8 encoding

Tags: c#, soap, unicode, utf-8, wsdl

I'm using automatic conversion from wsdl to c#, everything works apart from encoding, whenever
I have native characters (like 'ł' or 'ó') I get '??' insted of them in string fields ('G????wny' instead of 'Główny'). How to deal with it? Server sends document with correct encoding, with header .

EDIT: I noticed in Wireshark, that packets send FROM me have BOM, but packets sends TO me, don't have it - maybe it's a root of problem?

Comment: Please give details on what you mean by "automatic conversion from wsdl to c#". Did you use "Add Service Reference"?

Comment: Yes, exactly. I only gave it url address to wsdl document.

Comment: In general, this should work. You need to provide more details. Is this a service you wrote? Can you give details about the service? How are you calling the service?

Comment: I haven't written this service, and I call it by object deriving from SoapHttpClientProtocol (generated by c# ide), I only provide cookies container for it, and then call methods, that's it. I looked at wireshark on packets, and they are correctly coded as utf-8, so problem lays in generated code.

Comment: It is unlikely that the problem is in the generated code. It doesn't actually _do_ much. Also, strings in .NET are Unicode, so would not be losing special characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was on the server side with sent Content-Type parameter in header (it was set to "text/xml"). It occurs that for utf-8 it HAVE TO be "text/xml; charset=utf-8", other methods such as placing BOM aren't correct (according to RFC 3023). More info here: http://annevankesteren.nl/2005/03/text-xml

Answer (score 0):

So maybe the following will help:

What I am sure I did is:

In the webservice PHP file, after connecting to the Mysql Database I call:

> mysql_query("SET CHARSET utf8");
>
> mysql_query("SET NAMES `utf8` COLLATE `utf8_polish_ci`");

The second I did:

In the same PHP file,
I added `utf8_encode` to the service on the $POST_DATA variable:

> $server->service(utf8_encode($POST_DATA));

in the `class.nusoap_base.php` I changed:

> `//var $soap_defencoding = 'ISO-8859-1';
>
> var $soap_defencoding = 'UTF-8';`

and olso in the `nusoap.php` the same as above:

> //var $soap_defencoding = 'ISO-8859-1';
>
> var $soap_defencoding = 'UTF-8';

and in the `nusoap.php` file again:

> var $decode_utf8 = true;

Now I can send and receive properly encoded data.

Hope this helps.
Regards,